# How to change object state from a method in MATLAB (basic enquiry)

Tags: matlab, oop, octave

I have the following class in MATALB.

```
classdef MyClass

  properties
      a;
  end

  methods
      function foo(obj)
          obj.a = 1;            
      end  
  end
end
```

Now, I do this.

```
mc = MyClass;
mc.foo();
```

Now we have this.

```
mc.a == []
```

This is something I don't understand. I was expecting

```
mc.a == [1]
```

Why hasn't the function foo changed the state of the object?

I am sorry if this is a very basic question. I am used to languages like Java and C#, where the semantics is clearly according to what I'm expecting.

I've discovered that if I do the following, it works are expected.

```
classdef MyClass < handle
```

But how to get the desired behavior with a value class in MATLAB (i.e. not a handle class)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a value class is passed by value, not by reference, you need `foo` to return the updated object:

```
classdef MyClass

  properties
      a;
  end

  methods
      function obj = foo(obj)
          obj.a = 1;            
      end  
  end
end
```

Then

```
mc = MyClass;
mc = mc.foo();
```

This is why I only use handle classes.